# Different forms for update and create actions in ActiveAdmin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, action, activeadmin

Is it possible to have different forms for `update` and `create` actions **in ActiveAdmin**? How could I achieve this? I was looking for this for a while in documentation and I can't find anything.

Comment: Hmmm...can you be more specific? HTML? MySQL?

Comment: Will the forms differ by showing/hiding a few fields or will the entire display of form be significantly differ? It is possible to render different views for the `new` and `edit` actions, but it would not be within the ActiveAdmin DSL.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `object.new_record?` to check if the record is new or not.

For example:

```
    form do |f|
      if object.new_record? # new 
        f.inputs do
          f.input :name
          f.input :age
        end    
      else                  # update
        f.inputs do
          f.input :name
        end
      end

      f.actions
    end
```

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can

```
def new
end

def edit
end

def create
end

def udpate
end
```

And in your new template, have the form for create and in your edit template, have the form for update. When the user clicks on add new, hook it to new action. When the user clicks on update, hook it to edit

```
new.html.haml/new.html.erb

<form for create>

edit.html.haml/edit.html.erb

<form for update>
```